# React JS thumbnail gallery

Tags: reactjs

I am building a component which is a gallery that consists of a main gallery image and a list of thumbnails under the main image. This component will be used across multiple pages so each page will have it own thumbnails/images.  I have worked out how to get the correct images into the gallery depending on the page using redux and a store. However I cant figure out the functionality in getting the main image to change when the corresponding thumbnail is clicked, any ideas or suggestion how I could approach this?

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Gallery extends Component {

    render() {

        let img = this.props.bouq.map((el, index) => {
            return(
                <img src={"/images/" + el + ".jpg"} alt="." key={index}/>
            );     
        })

        return(
            <section className="gallery">

                    <div className="mainImage">
                        <img src='/images/bouquets.jpg' alt="."/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="thumbnails">
                        {img}   
                    </div>


            </section>

        );

    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        bouq: state.bouquets
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Gallery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the access to every individual element inside the `map`, onClick on an element, you can update you mainImage in your redux store.

You'll also need to create an action that updates the mainImage (depending on how you manage your redux actions)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { updateMainImage } from './actions'

class Gallery extends Component {
  updateMainImage = tumbnail => () => {
    this.props.dispatch(updateMainImage(thumbnail))
  }

  render() {
    const { mainImg, bouq } = this.props

    return (
      <section className="gallery">
        <div className="mainImage">
          <img src={`/images/${mainImage}.jpg`} alt={mainImage} />
        </div>

        <div className="thumbnails">
          {bouq.map(thum => (
            <img
              key={thumb}
              src={`/images/${thumb}.jpg`}
              alt={thumb}
              onClick={this.updateMainImage(thumb)}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    bouq: state.bouquets,
    mainImage: state.mainImage,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Gallery)
```

Comment: Looks like a great suggestion.  Will give this ago and let you know how it goes.  Appreciate the help!